# Transition property not working in Mozilla

Tags: css

I have a class with following properties

The transition is working fine in **Chrome** and in **Internet Explorer** but in **Firefox** its not working. Someone please tell me how to make it work in **Mozilla Firefox** also.

```
background-color: #fafafa;
width: 100%;
max-height:55px;
-webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
-moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
z-index:9999;
```

Comment: Why the transition prefixless is not in your rules ?

Comment: could you write some more code ?

Comment: i didnt understand you. I am fairly new to programming.Can u elaborate little more@CyrilBeeckman

Comment: share your full html code and full css code in your question

Comment: @Max Look my answer below, you didn't have specify the default "transition" property

Answer (score 2):

You should specify good transition rules and the default rule like this :

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Android 2.1+, Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6  */

transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+  */
```